# How to connect the various part in my Java EE Application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I am making a Java EE application just to use what I learn while reading in the books. I made a simple Entity and a DAO object that do different actions on this Entity such as create, update etc. Then in my EJB I want to use this DAO object so that I later can expose it to JSF etc.

I am having a little problems of understanding how to use objects of different classes in different layers of my application. How do I expose them to each other?

Do I just do as in regular Java SE? Have properties for the different classes and instantiate them in the classes I want? (No probably not, I have seen the use of @Inject and so on, but I do not understand one bit of it. And not when I can use it either)

I would apprciate some text on when/how we use the different annotations  and how we connect different layers rather than just some code showing it.

I am on the Java chat if anyone have some spare time =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking too general questions. Grab some decent book on Java EE (there are tons of them). For better understanding of dependency injection, I'd recommend official Weld [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html_single/). However here is a typical example aimed to show you how to connect different Java EE layers:

**JPA Entity**:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  //getters and setters
}
```

**EJB bean**:

```
@Stateless
public class EmployeeService {

  //The entity manager will be injected automatically  
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  public Employee findEmployeeById(Long id) {
    return em.find(Employee.class, id);
  }

}
```

**JSF controller** (let's assume it's CDI-bean):

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class EmployeeController implements Serializable {

  //using CDI @Inject annotation empService will be initialized automatically
  @Inject
  private EmployeeService empService;

  //this method can be called from .xhtml page
  public String obtainEmployeeName(Long id) {
    String empName = "";
    Employee emp = empService.findEmployeeById(id);
    if (emp != null) {
      empName = emp.getName();
    }
    return empName;
  }
}
```

**xhtml page**:

```
<h:outputText value="#{employeeController.obtainEmployeeName(3)}" />
```

**Update**
Some books that might help:

[Pro JPA 2: Mastering the Java Persistence API](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219564)

[Core JavaServer Faces (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137012896)

[Beginning Java EE 6 with GlassFish 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143022889X)

These are quite popular and cover a lot of ground.

Comment: But I still want to understand what I asked about in the question. When do I know I can use @Inject, what is it?, what is CDI? Books where this is written, good explanation tutorials etc is highly apprciated.

Comment: I added link to official Weld documentation in my answer. It does a good job explaining dependency injection mechanism.

Comment: I've also added some books that are highly recommended. Please, see the update.

Comment: @BPDeveloper I am on the same boat with you here, trying to understand DI. Maybe, it is not as complicated as it sounds though, if a class has a field, that field is a dependency of it, right? Instead of assigning it yourself, you inject it via other means, into the object -- hence the name dependency injection.

Comment: @ustun `if a class has a field, that field is a dependency of it, right?` - not unless it was annotated with @Inject. You may also use constructors and methods as injection points.

Comment: @ustun I started to read from the link now. After what I have understood you have the framework to create and instance of the object and then assign it to the reference instead of yourself doing it.

Comment: @BPDeveloper you may also want to check out great blog entries dedicated to CDI by `Beginning Java EE 6 with GlassFish 3` author, Antonio Goncalves [here](http://agoncal.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/injection-with-cdi-part-i/).